# Problem installing vtk package for python 3.8.10

Tags: python, vtk

I have problem installing vtk for python 3.8.10, using pip version 21.3 on a Windows10 x64 platform

```
$ pip install vtk
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement vtk (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for vtk
```

when I try to install the wheel:

```
$ pip install vtk-9.1.0-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl
ERROR: vtk-9.1.0-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

I've also tried to install older version of vtk without success.

Anyone has encounter this problem of know how to install vtk?

Comment: Hey are you on a 32-bit python or 64-bit python?

Comment: @Thornily 
I am on 64-bit python version 3.8.10: `C:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\Python>python --version`

Python 3.8.10`



`C:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\Python>python -c "import struct; print(struct.calcsize('P') * 8)"`

64

Answer (score 1):

`vtk` provides only 64-bit releases. Assuming your Python is 32-bit, it will not install. To install vtk you need to upgrade to 64-bit Python.

To check python bit-version:
`python -c "import struct; print(struct.calcsize('P') * 8)"`